# Commands to start and stop Nginx and how many nginx processes will be created?

Tags: nginx

I am new in using Nginx. I have two questions:

(a) I noticed that are two sets of commands to start and stop Nginx:

```
$ sudo nginx
$ sudo nginx -s stop
```

and

```
$ sudo service nginx start
$ sudo service nginx stop
```

What are the differences between them?

(b) Once Nginx is started, there are a number of its processes running. So, how many copies will be created and how does the system determine the number of processes to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A - In the first way you are using nginx executable to restart it, the second one uses built-in (I typically use it on Centos) operating system util which handles service scripts.

B - It is configured in nginx.conf, by default it is (as far as I remember) set to 2 working processes. Nginx always creates one master process as well

http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html